# Antlr4 simple tokenizing failing

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have the following grammar to lex/parse a string, all i am wanting at this point is to tokenize by spaces :

```
grammar MyItems;
theseItems : item (SPACE item)* ;
item : FIELDTEXT+ ;
SPACE : ' ' ;
FIELDTEXT : ~[' ']  ;
```

With input of :

```
V3 AGL V445
```

Gives me an error of :

```
line 1:0 mismatched input 'V3' expecting FIELDTEXT
```

Why does this not give me a set of 3 items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the posted grammar I don't have that error, but :

```
$ a4 MyItems_op.g4 
warning(180): MyItems_op.g4:5:13: chars "'" used multiple times in set [' ']
$ javac M*.java
$ grun MyItems_op theseItems -tokens -diagnostics input.text
[@0,0:0='V',<FIELDTEXT>,1:0]
[@1,1:1='3',<FIELDTEXT>,1:1]
[@2,2:2=' ',<' '>,1:2]
[@3,3:3='A',<FIELDTEXT>,1:3]
[@4,4:4='G',<FIELDTEXT>,1:4]
[@5,5:5='L',<FIELDTEXT>,1:5]
...
```

As you can see, the rule

```
FIELDTEXT : ~[' ']  ;
```

matches a single character.

Try this :

```
grammar MyItems;

theseItems
@init {System.out.println("MyItems last update 0030");}
    :   item (SPACE item)*
    ;

item
    :   FIELDTEXT
    ;

SPACE     : ' ' ;
FIELDTEXT : ~[ \r\n]+ ;

NL  : [\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

Execution :

```
$ alias
alias a4='java -jar /usr/local/lib/antlr-4.6-complete.jar'
$ a4 MyItems.g4 
$ javac M*.java
$ grun MyItems theseItems -tokens -diagnostics input.text 
[@0,0:1='V3',<FIELDTEXT>,1:0]
[@1,2:2=' ',<' '>,1:2]
[@2,3:5='AGL',<FIELDTEXT>,1:3]
[@3,6:6=' ',<' '>,1:6]
[@4,7:10='V445',<FIELDTEXT>,1:7]
[@5,12:11='<EOF>',<EOF>,2:0]
MyItems last update 0030
$ hexdump -C input.text 
00000000  56 33 20 41 47 4c 20 56  34 34 35 0a              |V3 AGL V445.|
0000000c
```

Comment: Hi Bernard, Thanks for your input. This did not solve my problem, although moving this grammar into another project did help. therefore I surmise that the error is an artifact of my setup.